# Cocos3d:Animation is not working in the output

Tags: cocos3d

I am developing cocos3d app for iOS.
I added the walk animation for a "Man" blend file. Looks, the man is doing walk animation fine in Blender. I have used the following settings to convert to collada and then pod. I am getting wrong output mentioned like below.

1. Export .dae options such as "Export Data Options (Apply modifiers, Selection only, Include Armatures are enabled),
2. Texture options (Include UV Textures, Include Material textures and copy are enabled),
3. Armature Options (Deform Bones only is enabled),
4. Collada Options (Use Object Instance enabled)

options enabled in Blender when converting to .dae file.

And then, In PVRGeoPOD 2.13 version,

1. Export Geometry (Primitive Type: Indexed Triangle list)
2. Use custom optimisations settings (PVRTGeomterySort sorting method), Vertex data optiomisations (Interleave Vertex data, align vertex data 32 bits)
3. Vector (Position - float, Normal - float, Color - RGBA)
4. Export Skinning data ( Bone indices - unsigned byte; Bone weights - unsigned bytes)
5. Matrix palette size - 11
6. Export Mapping Channels (uvw0 - float only enabled)
7. Flip V co-ordinate enabled
8. Material - 'Export Materials' only enabled
9. Transformations - Export animations, Index animation data are enabled. Co-ordinate system - OpenGL model space

OUTPUT:
A Man walking animation is happening kind of, but the man is completed black shaded and bones are unlikely expanded. Output is ugly one.

Please note: If i add the same Man without adding "Armature (and bone, walk animation)" in blender and the exported pod is showing the man very well in the device output without any animation.

Output 1: When i added walk animation using armature bones, output is black shaded with improper walk animation. Pls. refer this link to see output
https://www.yousendit.com/download/UVJpWUh0bThiV3dsYzhUQw

Output 2: Output without any animation in that Man pod model. Pls refer this link.
https://www.yousendit.com/download/UVJpWUh0bThoMlhyZHNUQw

I have uploaded the .blend, .pod files attached in this link -> https://www.yousendit.com/download/UVJpWUhndWNsUjk3czlVag

How do i solve the animation issue and provide the smooth walk animation with clear view? As i need to fix this issue urgently, could you please help on suggesting to solve this issue?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Here is the solution-> http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/345818